# why mu user model throws an error like filter_horizontal

Tags: django, django-models, backend

Below is my Django user model . as you can see i created two different models and sync them on a foreign keys but I can't migrate my project

```
# accounts/models.py

from django.db import models

class MyUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    NationalID=models.IntegerField(unique=True,max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Mykeys(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(MyUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public_key = models.TextField(unique=False)
    private_key = models.TextField(unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.public_key
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: diffrent runs most important one cant create accounts_myuser relation